# How to get Google URL in php

Tags: php

I am working on a project where My application should return the result only. For example if my question is Who is the current prime minister of India then my App should show Narendra Modi only.

For that i need the URL For that question. Then only i can extract the particular content of that webpage.

here i just copied and pasted the URL.

So guys help me to find out how to get the Google URL for that question.

```
  <?PHP

 include 'simple_html_dom.php';

     $html =file_get_html('http://www.google.co.in/searchq=current+prime+minister+of+india&oq=current+prime+minister+of+united+states&gs_l=serp.3..35i39k1j0i22i30k3.3565      7.38471.0.38639.13.1
 3.0.0.0.0.234.1360.10j2j1.13.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.13.1359...0i67k1.PZp_2BbQkC8');


$ret = $html->find('span[class=_m3b]');


 foreach($ret as $var)
 {
  echo $var;
 }




 ?>
```

Comment: man you must have alot of faith that google is going to give you, and the user, the correct answer they are looking for.

Comment: Semi-Off-Topic: You know, the united states does not have a prime minister? They have a "President". But that's another story.

Comment: i just need the URL which is google going to use for a question that's all.

Comment: Yeah @ManuToMatic That's another story.. i ll write separate code to manage that... All i need is the URL for the resulting webpage if i typed who is the current prime minister of India in the google search box. that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally google uses URL as follows..

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=primeminister

The search value is passed as query parameter.

$search = $_POST['search_value'];

use `file_get_contents()` to get the value.

For Eg:

```
file_get_contents("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=".$search);
```

From this you can sort the result.